# set credential in keycloak

Tags: java, authentication, keycloak

I have such method for changing user's first name in keycloak's database.

```
    public void changeUserFirstname(FirstNameChangeDto firstNameChangeDto) {
    //todo
    log.log(Level.INFO, "requested change of firstname for user " + firstNameChangeDto.getEmail());

    Keycloak keycloak = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
            .serverUrl(config.getKeycloak().getAuthServerUrl())
            .grantType(OAuth2Constants.PASSWORD)
            .realm("master")
            .username(config.getKeycloak().getAdminLogin())
            .password(config.getKeycloak().getAdminPass())
            .clientId(config.getKeycloak().getAdminClientId())
            .build();

    log.info("Found {} realms", keycloak.realms().findAll().size());
    UsersResource usersResource = keycloak.realm(config.getKeycloak().getRealm()).users();

    Optional<UserRepresentation> userRepresentationOptional = usersResource.search(firstNameChangeDto.getEmail()).stream().findFirst();



    if(userRepresentationOptional.isPresent()) {
        UserResource userResource = usersResource.get(userRepresentationOptional.get().getId());
        userResource.setCredentialUserLabel("username", firstNameChangeDto.getFirstName());
        System.out.println("fsfs");
    }else{
        System.out.println("here");
    }
    keycloak.realm("ed24").clearUserCache();
    System.out.println("");
```

The problem is that it throws an error

```
2021-06-07 21:02:16.967 ERROR 1 --- [nio-9080-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is    javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found] with root cause

    javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found
```

How can I correctly change the firstname for the user? How can I check the actual id of the firstname? I'm guessing that it is username in this case. Keycloak is very poorly documented and I searching phrase `userResource.setCredentialUserLabel()` in Google gave me only documentation and the code itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out. I had to get the `UserResource` class

```
        UserResource userResource = getUserResource(keycloak, firstNameChangeDto.getEmail());
```

then simply after updating

```
        UserRepresentation userRepresentation = userResource.toRepresentation();
        userRepresentation.setFirstName(firstNameChangeDto.getFirstName());
```

use update method

```
        userResource.update(userRepresentation);
```